# How to change values inside a picker using @Published property wrapper in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, picker

hi am having issues with the picker view in swiftui

i have created one file with just a class like this

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


class something: ObservableObject {

    
    @Published var sel = 0
}
```

and then I created 2 views

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var hihi: something
    
    var characters = ["Makima", "Ryuk", "Itachi", "Gojou", "Goku", "Eren", "Levi", "Jiraya", "Ichigo", "Sukuna"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section{
                Picker("Please choose a character", selection: $hihi.sel) {
                    ForEach(characters, id: \.self) { name in
                        Text(name)
                    }
                }
                Text(characters[hihi.sel])

            }
            now(hihi: something())
        }
    }
}


struct now: View {
    
    @StateObject var hihi: something
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(hihi.sel)")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(hihi: something())
    }
}
```

now the problem am facing is that the code compiles but the picker ain't working it won't change to any other value in the array I have provided it recoils back to its original value provided that is 0th index "Makima" and it won't select any other option, why so?
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems, the main one being the mismatching selection.

In the `Picker`, your selection is based on the string value for each character. This is because the `ForEach` identifies each `Text` by the `name` string, since you used `id: \.self`.

However, your `something` model (which ideally should start with a capital letter by convention) has a numeric selection. Because the items in the `Picker` have `String` IDs, and this is an `Int`, the selection can't be set.

You can change your model to this:

```
class something: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sel = "Makima"
}
```

Which also requires a slight change in the body:

```
VStack {
    Section{
        Picker("Please choose a character", selection: $hihi.sel) {
            ForEach(characters, id: \.self) { name in
                Text(name)
            }
        }
        Text(hihi.sel) // Now getting string directly

    }
    now(hihi: something())
}
```

Notice we now have two views showing the selected character - but only the top one updates. The bottom one may now be redundant (the `now` view), but I'll show you how you can get it working anyway. This is where we encounter the 2nd problem:

You are creating a new instance of `something()` when passing it to `now` (again, should start with a capital). This means that the current instance of `hihi` stored in `ContentView` is not passed along. You are just creating a new instance of `something`, which uses the default value. This is completely independent from the `hihi` instance.

Replace:

```
now(hihi: something())
```

With:

```
now(hihi: hihi)
```

The final problem, which may not be as visible, is that you shouldn't be using `@StateObject` in `now`, since it doesn't *own* the object/data. Instead, the object is passed in, so you should use `@ObservedObject` instead. Although the example now works even without this change, you will have issues later on when trying to change the object within the `now` view.

Replace `@StateObject` in `now` with `@ObservedObject`.

---

Full answer (`something` is initialized in `ContentView` only for convenience of testing):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var hihi: something = something()

    var characters = ["Makima", "Ryuk", "Itachi", "Gojou", "Goku", "Eren", "Levi", "Jiraya", "Ichigo", "Sukuna"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section{
                Picker("Please choose a character", selection: $hihi.sel) {
                    ForEach(characters, id: \.self) { name in
                        Text(name)
                    }
                }
                Text(hihi.sel)

            }
            now(hihi: hihi)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct now: View {
    @ObservedObject var hihi: something

    var body: some View {
        Text(hihi.sel)
    }
}
```

```
class something: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sel = "Makima"
}
```